# Two questions on topological and geometric structure of projections in a simple $C^{*}$ algebra

Tags: riemannian-geometry, oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

1. Let $A$ be a simple $C^{*}$ algebra. Assume  that the space of projections has a connected component homeomorphic to the complex  Grassmanian $G(k,n)$. Is it true to say that, for  all $k'<k$, the  space  of projections has a connected component homeomorphic to $G(k',n)$?

This is motivated by the situation of   matrix  algebra.

2.There is  a natural  homeomorphism between projections of $M_{2}(\mathbb{C})$  and  $S^{2}$, as  a  metric  subspace of  $\mathbb{R}^{3}$,  which sends $1/2 \begin{pmatrix} 1-z&x+yi \\x-yi&1+z\end{pmatrix}$ to $(x,y,z)$. Note that this  homeomorphism is an isometry, up to a constant. This  is  a motivation to ask the following two questions:

**Q1:** Is the space of projections in $M_{2}(\mathbb{C}$) a submanifold with constant sectional curvature.(Motivated by the above isometry and the fact that the sphere has constant curvature). We equip $M_{2}(\mathbb{C})$ with the natural reimannian  metric)

**Q2:**  Is there  a  canonical isometry between  projections of matrix  algebra with trace $k$ and $G(k,n)$ (with their natural metrics)?